# Creat a bootable USB of windows 10 on ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, windows

How can i make a bootable USB of windows 10 on ubuntu ? 
I tried to extract the iso on the usb key but all i got was an error when i tried to install it.

How can i make a bootable USB of Windows 10 using Ubuntu ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Not specifically an Ubuntu question:

UEFI only USB key, just extract ISO ( 7 zip or similar) to FAT32 formated flash & set boot flag.

[How to create UEFI-only bootable USB live media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media)

Windows 7, 8, 10 BIOS or UEFI boot installer from Ubuntu
More details:

http://onetransistor.blogspot.ch/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html